# How to fix: RuntimeError: Function AddmmBackward returned an invalid gradient index 1got [100, 4096] but expected shape compatible with [100, 200704]

Tags: deep-learning

def **init**(self):
super().**init**()

```
    self.conv1 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(2),
    )
    self.conv2 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(2),
    )
    self.conv3 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(2),
    )
    self.fc = nn.Linear(4*4*256,10)
```

for epoch in range(epochs):
train_loss = 0
train_acc = 0
for data, target in train_loader:

```
    data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
    logits = net(data)
    loss = criteon(logits, target)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    **loss.backward()**
    optimizer.step()

    _,pred = logits.max(1)
    num_correct = (pred==target).sum().item()
    acc = num_correct / data.shape[0]
    train_acc += acc

    train_loss += loss.data
```

Comment: Getting error for loss.backward()

Comment: For future readers, if you've come here after facing this error in transformer based models, check whether you're using BertModel/BertForMaskedLM correctly.